# How to deal with kubernetes CPU requests that are only needed during startup

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, azure-aks

I've got a bunch of Java (spring boot) microservices that require **a lot** of CPU when booting compared to when they are done starting up. I need at least 400m to get my pod started within 5minutes, where afterwords my pods only use on average 10m.

I'm a bit in doubt what now is a wise strategy. I'm deliberately not setting CPU limits, but previously have set my CPU requests pretty low (20m). If an entire node get's evicted, pods get the minimal amount of CPU and aren't able to successfully startup (obviously if only 1 pod boots there is now problem). If I schedule all my microservices with 400m I'll have a huge amount of unused resources when nothing is really happening.

Is there a way for Kubernetes to be less strict on resource requests, provisioning more pods than strictly allowed when taking the sum of my requests?

The answer in the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60967380/startup-cpu-limit-for-java-applications-in-kubernetes) suggests to just remove CPU limits (what I'm already doing), so I guess they would suggest you should give your pods the "low" amount of CPU requests. Then pods can get scheduled with too little resources to startup, moving into a crashloop, wouldn't that be an anti pattern?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Startup-CPU-Limit for Java Applications in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60967380/startup-cpu-limit-for-java-applications-in-kubernetes)

Comment: So that solution suggests you just omit CPU limits (what I'm already doing), so I guess then would suggest you give your pods the "low" amount of CPU requests. Then pods can get scheduled with too little resources to startup, moving into a crashloop, wouldn't that be an anti pattern?

Comment: From your last line in your question I make up that you think that if you don't provide a limit, the limit is similar to the requested. But that is not the case!
See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/#if-you-do-not-specify-a-cpu-limit

When not providing a limit, the resource is limitless or bound to namespace limit.
So I think that in your situation, only providing a resource request with the minimum needed would be most suitable. This should give maximum resources at startup.

Comment: But then pods can still get scheduled on nodes with not enough resources available right?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a [Vertical Pod Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler) which adjusts the CPU and memory based on visible usage. So you could ask for a lot of memory and CPU up front and the VPA should reduce those later over time.

YMMV though, I've never used it with a spring boot app, but give it a go and see if it works for you.

Comment: Hmm this seems like a good idea, I'll dive into this and see if it works for my use case. Thanks.

Comment: Careful, until the mutable resources arrive (alpha 1.27, GA 1.32), VPA recreates pods when changing their requests...